# Flat ISP network to MPLS dumb Q

Tags: networking, cisco, isp, mpls

I have a fairly flat ISP network that I am upgrading to use MPLS (dont ask why, that decision is above my position) but clients/CPE are authenticated using PPPoE. Each POP uses a router configured as an LAC with a L2TP-tunnel to a LNS stack. Client information is stored in a Radius server.

I have these requirements:
1)Must use PPPoE to authenticate clients/CPE
2)avoid adding more traffic to the network as much as possible
3)Maintain IS-IS as the IGP (if IS-IS needs to go, provide valid reasons that I can use)
4)try not to use additional vendors equipment, Currently Cisco is the default with some Linksys (Cisco) equipment.

What I am planning is to just use an AToM tunnel to the LNS stack and adding MPLS to each router.

Any other ideas?

Comment: People use IS-IS?

Comment: Yes we do, and prefer it to OSPF (each person perfers a different routing protocol). IS-IS is much simpler IMO to OSPF due to no mucking about with areas if not needed and it is a more mature (is what the big guys use so gets updated more quickly) protocol. Not saying OSPF shouldnt be used, just that we dont. Most dont use IS-IS due to the issue of net names eg 49.0001.0100.0102.0001.01 once you understand that the first two sets are the network, then nest 3 are the router ID (loopback ip) and the last is not used if not needed then its just as quick to config as OSPF.

Comment: That aside, you can run one, two or all routing protocols at the same time if you wish/need. just setup the proper leaks so that there is no trouble with a peer only speaking one protocol trying to send to another peer that only speaks another.

Comment: When you say MPLS, you mean a L3 connection through another provider, a CsC config, or something else?  Also don't lose track of the MTU considerations of tunneling any traffic.

Comment: no other provider,all our own network. just making the l2 flat network less flat. each pop has a switch and a router that acts as an LAC. The net goal is to offer enhanced services (bridging of client networks over ours, point to point and multi-point) and reduce the network overhead of multiple route look-ups.